# Codeigniter, How to get database table data displayed in json format?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have to display the result in json format.
my code looks like:

```
 $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('country');  
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
```

and the result looks like:

```
{"id":"1","country_name":"Australia","country_code":"61"}{"id":"2","country_name":"Bangladesh","country_code":"880"}{"id":"3","country_name":"Brazil","country_code":"55"}
```

I have to get this json in [] and separated by comma (,) . that is I want the result looks like:

```
[{"id":"1","country_name":"Australia","country_code":"61"},{"id":"2","country_name":"Bangladesh","country_code":"880"},{"id":"3","country_name":"Brazil","country_code":"55"}]
```

what all changes should I done in the code.

Comment: Get all rows in an array and encode the result.

Comment: foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
          $data['id']=$row->id;
          $data['country_name']=$row->country_name;
            echo json_encode($data);
        }   not working but the result looks same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve the record in array and then encode it

```
$result = $this->db->get('country')->result_array();
print_r(json_encode($result));
```

Answer (score 2):

In model write

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `result_array()`.

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('country');  
$query = $this->db->get();

foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo json_encode($row);
}
```